# Observable caching and cache clearing without invalidating subscriptions in Angular

Tags: angular, caching, observable

I have two components that both use data retrieved from an API endpoint over http. I want to cache the response from the API endpoint so only one http request is made, but I also want to be able to clear the cache when I know data has changed so that the two components are updated via their original subscriptions.

I can get caching to work so only one http request is made by using `publishReplay(1)`. But I can't find a way to invalidate the cache with that method.

I've tried creating my own observable and calling `next()` when I don't already have a cached version of the data, but I can't figure out how I might redefine the observer function so it returns different data when I invalidate the cache.

```
class ApiService {
  private user$: Observable<User>;
  ...
  getUser() {
    if (!this.user$)
      this.user$ = this.http.get<User>(`${apiUrl}users/me`).pipe(shareReplay(1));
    return this.user$;
  }

  invalidateUserCache() {
    // do what? Can't assign a new observable to this.user$ because 
    // any components that have already subscribed won't be notified
    // of the updates
  }
}

class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getUser().subscribe(user => this.user = user);
  }
  updateUser() {
    this.api.updateUser(someData).subscribe(response => {
      this.api.invalidateUserCache();
      // Since cache has been invalidated, I want this to 
      // make a new http request and notify other components 
      // that have subscribed.
      this.api.getUser().subscribe(user => this.user = user);
    }
  }
}

class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getUser().subscribe(user => this.user = user);
  }
}
```

The above code caches the User object so only one http request is made, but if `UserProfileComponent` updates the user, `MenuComponent` is not updated with the new user.

Comment: Did you consider using BehaviorSubject ? 
Behaviorsubject exactly does what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

At Jeyenth's suggestion of using BehaviorSubject, I came up with this:

```
class ApiService {
  private _user: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  ...
  getUser() {
    if (!this._user) { // we haven't already requested the current user
      this._user = new BehaviorSubject(null);
      this.http.get<User>(`${apiUrl}users/me`).subscribe(user => this._user.next(user));
    }
    return this._user;
  }

  refreshUser() {
    this.http.get<User>(`${apiUrl}users/me`).subscribe(user => this._user.next(user));
  }
}
```

It works perfectly. Thanks Jeyenth!

Comment: Would it be better to use ReplaySubject? If we subscribe to BehaviorSubject, does the first value we get from it (null) have to be filtered?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the cache, you simply set the reference value `this.user$` to null. Then when the method `getUser()` is executed again, it will run a new server request which then updates the previous stored cache.

```
 clearCache() {
    this.user$= null;
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve the subscription from the other component. It does clear the cache for the component calling getUser(), but no other components can then be updated because the original observable has been lost.